# Error during wrapup: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, function, dataframe, debugging, linear-regression

I keep getting this error message, I am not too sure what went wrong as I am trying to do a linear regression analysis.

Ind_v is the independent variable and dep_v is the dependent variable. I switched the data.frame to [] and it doesn't work as well. Thank you so much, everyone!

I split the training and test data to 70/30.

```
linear_regression <- function(training_dataset, 
                                  test_dataset, 
                                  dependent_variables,
                                  independent_variables){

formular_me <- paste(dependent_variables, "~", independent_variables)
linear_model <- lm(formula = formular_me, data = training_dataset)

ind_v_from_test_dataset <- subset(test_dataset,select=independent_variables)

linear_model_analysis <- predict(linear_model,ind_v_from_test_dataset)

dep_v_from_test_dataset <- test_dataset[,dependent_variables]

RMSE_me <- round(Nrmse(actual = dep_v_from_test_dataset, predicted = linear_model_analysis),digits=2)
MAE_me <- round(Nmae(actual = dep_v_from_test_dataset,predicted = linear_model_analysis),digits=2)
R2_me <- round(Nr2(linear_model_analysis),digits=2)

linear_analysis_error <- dep_v_from_test_dataset - linear_model_analysis
linear_results<- data.frame(dep_v_from_test_dataset,ind_v_from_test_dataset,linear_analysis_error)
linear_results<- linear_analysis_error[order(ind_v_from_test_dataset),]

plot(linear_results[,independent_variables],
     linear_results$ind_v_from_test_dataset,
     pch=4,
     ylab="dependent variable",
     xlab="independent variables",
     main="Linear Regression Errors",
     sub=paste("MAE=",mae,"RMSE=",RMSE," R2=",r2))


abline(linear_model,col = "blue", lwd=6)


suppressWarnings(arrows(linear_results[,ind_v_from_test_dataset],
                        linear_results$dep_v_from_test_dataset,
                        linear_results[,independent_variables],
                        linear_results$dep_v_from_test_dataset-linear_results$error,
                        length=0.05,angle=90,code=3,col="red"))

return(
  list(RMSE_me=RMSE,
  MAE_me=mae,
  R2_me=r2))
```

}

Comment: this is the code I want to run for the function
  linear_regression(training_dataset = training_data, 
                          test_dataset = testing_data,
                          dependent_variables = "medv",
                          independent_variables = "nox")

Comment: the data is called Boston

Comment: Perhaps change `linear_results$ind_v_from_test_dataset` to `linear_results[,ind_v_from_test_dataset]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to put the data and code there: comments can easily be missed by readers or hidden by the interface.